# Multiple filters functionality not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of objects in the below format. If `IsEnabled` is `0`, the value shown in UI is `Disabled` and for `IsEnabled` value `1`, the value is `Enabled`.

```
[
    {
      AlertID: "A1"
      DisplayName: "B1"
      Group: "C1"
      IsEnabled: 0
    },
    {
      AlertID: "A2"
      DisplayName: "B2"
      Group: "C2"
      IsEnabled: 0
    },
  ]
```

I have a function for filtering out the data from all the 4 columns. When I try to filter out the values from IsEnabled, the other filters doesn't work. Filtering only the Enabled and Disabled alone works fine.

```
multiFilter(data: any[], filters) {
    const filterableColumns = Object.keys(this.sortedsearchkeys);
    const result = filterableColumns.reduce((acc, field) => {
      if (Array.isArray(filters[field]) && filters[field].length) {
        if(filters.IsEnabled[0] === 'Enabled') {
                return acc.filter((item) => {
                           return item.IsEnabled == 1
                        });
            }
        else if(filters.IsEnabled[0] === 'Disabled') {
                    return acc.filter((item) => {
                              return item.IsEnabled == 0
                            });
                }
                
       return acc.filter((item) => {
          return filters[field]?.length && filters[field].indexOf(item[field]) > -1
        });
      } 
      else {
        return acc;
      }
    }, data);
    return result;
  }
```

I am not able to figure out how to filter out the `Enabled/Disabled` along with the other 2 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check for `IsEnabled` in *each* iteration, irrespective of what `field` is. Instead you should check whether `field` really is about `IsEnabled` and only then perform the logic that is specific to this field:

```
if (field == "IsEnabled") {
    let target = ["Disabled", "Enabled"].indexOf(filters.IsEnabled[0]);
    return acc.filter((item) => {
        return item.IsEnabled == target;
    });
}
```